# Let S be a K3 surface and $C \subset S $ a smooth nonhyperelliptic curve of genus $g \geq 1$. Morphism defined by the linear system |C| is birational.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let S be a complex algebraic K3 surface and $C \subset S $ a smooth curve of genus $g $. If $g \geq 1 $ then the system |C| is without base points so it defines a morphism $\phi : S \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^g$ and the restriction of  $\phi$ to $C $ is the canonical morphism. Now, Hartshorne IV Proposition 5.2 tells us that for $g \geq 2$ $K_C$ is very ample if and only if C is non-hyperelliptic. So when C is non-hyperelliptic we have that the restriction of  $\phi$ to $C $ is an embedding. So we have $\phi^{-1}\phi (C)=C $. How could one conclude from this that $\phi$ is a birational morphism?

Comment: you proved that $\phi$ is an embedding on a general element of $|C|$, this implies that $\phi$ separates two general points of $S$, which means that it is birational.